# Rating for the outlet does not match the breaker.

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet for an air conditioner that is rated at 20a 250v. The breaker has 2, 20amp breakers. Should I be concerned?  Should i replace this outlet?

Answer (score 2):

That's fine.  The two breakers offer either 20 ampere protection to two 120 volt circuits, or 20 ampere protection to a single 240 volt circuit.

Comment: Note that in a 240 v installation, the two breakers should have a bar across them so that flipping one requires flipping the other.